# Terraform : Creating two AWS EC2 instance and pass private IP from variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new in terraform, I have problem while creating ec2 instance, my condition is, I am passing `private_Ips` values from variable file (like IP pool) and creating two ec2 instance so when I run `terraform apply` first time it creates two ec2 instances, but when second time I run `terraform apply` it says IP already in use, its not going to take 3rd and 4th IP. I want on 2nd run it for it to take 3rd and 4th IPs. Below are my definitions. Could you please suggest:

**var.tf**

```
variable "private_ips" {

   default = {

    "0" = "x.x.x.x"

    "1" = "x.x.x.x"

    "2" = "x.x.x.x"

    "3" = "x.x.x.x"

  }

}
```

**main.tf**

```
  private_ip = "${lookup(var.private_ips,count.index)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is a stateful tool. So, whenever it creates some pieces of infrastructure it **keeps track** of them (in what is called [Terraform state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/index.html)). The whole idea is that if you run `terraform apply` the first time it creates some infrastructure. And any subsequent run just **updates** whatever has been created before (with whatever changes were applied in `.tf` files).

You might want to read up on [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) whose idea is about using the same configuration (`.tf` files) against multiple independent copies of target infrastructure. Typically used for dev/test/prod kind of setups. It might be what you are after.